# How to stay in the same location after an alert?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an alert box in JavaScript which is prompted by clicking a link down the page. When the alert box pops up, and the user presses ok, the user is redirected to the top of the page. How do I make it so the page stays where the user prompted the alert box? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `return false;` to the end of the link.

`<a href="#" onclick="alert('Hello, World!'); return false;"`>